# Visual Studio (Git provider) permanently shows "pending edit" on all files

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using VS 2015 Community and Reshaper. My problem is that after pull or commit (using tortoise git client) VS still still shows "pending edit" on almost all files. "Compare with unmodified" show no change not event whitespaces. This getting me crazy because I want to see "pending edit" only on files I am actually working on ...

EDIT:
I just find that problem is with CRLF setting in git. I need line end with CRLF but git returns LF.

EDIT 2: After new informations I did following step which works for me:

1. Set line endings to CRLF: **`git config --global core.autocrlf true`**
2. Clear git indexes: **`git rm --cached -r .`**
3. Rewrite indexes - pick up all the new line endings: **`git reset --hard`**

More about line endings for windows [here](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-windows).

Comment: Compare with unmodified *doesn't show* whitespace changes.  What version of VS 2015?  Does Update 1 change this behavior?  What are your CRLF settings?

Comment: So I just find that I need end line with CRLF. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

I have heard of this before being caused by the "end of line" character in your files.

Try running this:

> git config --global core.autocrlf false

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is Windows, the [recommendation](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-windows) is to set `core.autocrlf` to true:-

> git config --global core.autocrlf true

Then, if the problem still persists in VS 2015 for your solution, check the solution's `.gitattributes` file.  Mine contained:-

> * text=auto

which was causing unwanted Pending Edits to still be shown (in VS 2015 but not in TortoiseGit).  I didn't need the `.gitattributes` file, so I deleted it, and then everything displayed as it should in VS 2015.